# Show Loading Gif on Page Link Click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm simply trying to show a loading gif, when you click any of the top/main links on my site at http://www.reverbstudios.ie. It kinda works but only for the first click. Subsequent clicks don't show the loading gif.

Here's the code I got from another site, I know very little about jQuery/Ajax/Javascript:

```
var AjaxContent = function(){
    var container_div = ''; 
    var content_div = ''; 
    return {
        getContent : function(url){
            $(container_div).animate({opacity:0}, //Turn the opacity to 0
                    function(){ // the callback, loads the content with ajax                        
                        $(container_div).find("#loading").show();
                        $(container_div).load(url+" "+content_div, //only loads the selected portion
                        function(){                        
                           $(container_div).animate({opacity:1}); //and finally bring back the opacity back to 1
                           $(container_div).find("#loading").hide();                           
                    }
                );        
            });
        },
        ajaxify_links: function(elements){
            $(elements).click(function(){
                $('#loading').show();
                AjaxContent.getContent(this.href);
                return false; //prevents the link from beign followed
            });
        },
        init: function(params){ //sets the initial parameters
            container_div = params.containerDiv; 
            content_div = params.contentDiv;
            return this; //returns the object in order to make it chainable
        }
    }
}()

/* Ajax Content Loading Controls */
$(function(){
        AjaxContent.init({containerDiv:".content_background",contentDiv:"#text"}).ajaxify_links("#nav a");
    });
```

Comment: How does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, I understood that `loading` div is placed inside `containerDiv`.

And the following line overrides all the data inside `containerDiv`. You should try moving the `loading` div out of `containerDiv`. And this should fix the problem.

```
$(container_div).load(url+" "+content_div, //only loads the selected portion
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: That doesn't work. Only thing that changes is the loading gif stays on screen and won't go away!